# get method name on a button or input on html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get a method name called on a button like this:

```
<button onclick="MyFunction">Button 1</button>

<input type="button" name="hola" value ="hola"onclick="MyFunction2">
```

I want to get "MyFunction" or "MyFunction2" method names from the buttons

```
    <script>
function MyFunction(){
**//sample method**
Alert("hola mundo");
}
function MyFunction2(){
**//sample method**
Alert("hola mundo2");
}
 </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"get a method name"_?

Comment: the word "MyFunction" and "Myfunction2"

Comment: theElement.getAttribute('onclick') will get you the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getAttribute method in order to retrieve the name of the function on the onclick attribute:

```
var buttonElement = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var buttonFunctionName = buttonElement.getAttribute("onclick");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5xLLq7n5/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a button with id="clickme" and onclick="myfunc"

To get the onclick function in a script use:

`document.getElementById("clickme").onclick // returns reference to myfunc`

To get the method name of onclick use:

`document.getElementById("clickme").onclick.name // returns "myfunc"`